# Smooth function not analytic at any $ x$

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist function $ f $ that is smooth but not analytic for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$?
($f $ is a Real-valued function)

Comment: i want to find not analytic for all $x \in R$

Comment: not one point, i find not analytic for all $ x \in Z$

Comment: See also [A smooth function which is nowhere real analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#A_smooth_function_which_is_nowhere_real_analytic) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

$$\phi(x) =  e^{-1/(1-x^2)} 1_{|x|< 1}\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}), \qquad \Phi(x) =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-e^{e^k}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \phi(2^k x+n) \in  C^\infty(\Bbb{R})$$